# A local or parameter named 'ContactForm' cannot be declared in this scope because

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a partial view containing a quick contact form.
The contact form should be rendered from the `_Layout`, without passing a model, like so

```
 @Html.Partial("_QuickContact")
```

Within the `_QuickContact` view i thought of declaring a variable like so

```
@{ContactForm ContactForm = new ContactForm();}
```

so i can i use it as

```
 <div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(ContactForm => ContactForm.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(ContactFormm => ContactForm.Email)
 </div>
```

since i would not like to pass a model at it. (This approach if i am not mistaken, would require tuples or a wrapper containing multiple models).

Unfortunately i get the error

> A local or parameter named 'ContactForm' cannot be declared in this
>   scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define
>   a local or parameter

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Your partial needs a `@model ContactForm` declaration (and then use `@Html.Partial("_QuickContact", new ContactForm())`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you post it as an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You model needs a `@model ContactForm` declaration, and then you can use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)` etc.

However because you calling this using `@Html.Partial()`, you need to pass a model (which can be a default instance) to the partial, otherwise the model in the main view will be passed and an exception will be thrown.

```
@Html.Partial("_QuickContact", new ContactForm())
```

The alternative would be to use a `Html.Action()` to call a server method that returns your partial, for example

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult Contact
{
    return PartialView("_QuickContact"); // or return PartialView("_QuickContact", new ContactForm());
}
```

and in the layout

```
@Html.Action("Contact") // or @{ Html.RenderAction("Contact"); }
```